# Implementing AdMob in my iOS app, error no ad to show

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Swift 4.2, iOS 12.x

Trying to implement AdMob in my app, but not getting very far.

1. Created an adMob account, looks ok?
2. Added NSAppTransportSecurity keys to info.plist ok?
3. Added this code to load an banner add ok.

   ```
   bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSize(size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 50), flags: 0), origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
   bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-A/B" // changed this code in this post
   bannerView.rootViewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
   bannerView.delegate = self
   let request = GADRequest()
   request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
   bannerView.load(request)
   self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(bannerView)
   ```

Extended class to support GADBannerViewDelegate; getting a call back on it which says error, no ad to show. The console in fact reports this.

> 2018-12-18 11:49:35.468445+0100 DeX[1547:900808] WF:
>   _WebFilterIsActive returning: YES 2018-12-18 11:49:35.468729+0100 DeX[1547:900808] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
>       filterBlacklist =     (
>       );
>       filterWhitelist =     (
>       );
>       noOverridingAllowed = 1;
>       restrictWeb = 1;
>       useContentFilter = 1;
>       useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
>       whitelistEnabled = 0; } 2018-12-18 11:49:35.468821+0100 DeX[1547:900808] WF: Checking if
>   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html
>   is in contentFilterOverriddenBlackList 2018-12-18 11:49:35.469159+0100
>   DeX[1547:900808] WF: Checking if
>   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html
>   is in contentFilterOverriddenWhiteList 2018-12-18 11:49:35.513610+0100
>   DeX[1547:900808] WF: *** WFLSMMap initWithMap: unable to retrieve
>   threshold from map file. 2018-12-18 11:49:35.518259+0100
>   DeX[1547:900808] WF: WFLSMScoreNormalizedMap category:1 min:0.338760
>   max:0.663066 scope:0.324306 2018-12-18 11:49:35.518377+0100
>   DeX[1547:900808] WF: WFLSMScoreNormalizedMap category:2 min:0.336934
>   max:0.661240 scope:0.324306 2018-12-18 11:49:35.518439+0100
>   DeX[1547:900808] WF: +[WFJudge defaultJudge]
>   map:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebContentAnalysis.framework/content_filter_map3
>   2018-12-18 11:49:35.518559+0100 DeX[1547:900808] WF: Page not worth
>   analyzing [pageContent length]:7 [[self images] count]==0 [[self
>   scriptBlocks] count]:2 2018-12-18 11:49:35.518693+0100
>   DeX[1547:900808] WF: WebFilterEvaluator:addData:
>   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html
>   is not blocked: 'googleads.g.doubleclick.net' is not explicit
>   2018-12-18 11:49:35.518760+0100 DeX[1547:900808] WF:
>   WebFilterEvaluator:addData: 'googleads.g.doubleclick.net' at
>   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html
>   is not blocked
>   *** error *** Request Error: No ad to show.

What have I missed out here? Created the account yesterday afternoon, so less than 24 hours past since I did so?

Comment: This line is the culprit `bannerUIView.rootViewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Limit Ad Tracking (in Settings/Privacy/Advertising) to off.

Comment: Tried this too. No change. Thanks anyway Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Just change you **AdUnitID** and **rootviewcontroller**.
Following code, I used and its working fine.
Can you please try to use this code

```
       let bannerView = GADBannerView.init(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 64, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50)
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-2205403669616327/4045941432" // changed this code in this post
        bannerView.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
        bannerView.load(request)
        bannerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        bannerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
```

Comment: The rootviewcontroller is correct, the code is within a SKScene. But my adUnitID evidently isn't working and this one is!!

Comment: This one from google works too ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716; nothing wrong with my code, something wrong with the adUintID I got issued it seems... or indeed it simply isn't quite cooked yet.

Comment: Just received a message from Google telling me mID is approved and added an add Unit to my app. This works!! Also changed the request.testDevices to hex code reported in the console, as per some instructions I seem to have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Use bannerView.rootViewController = self

Comment: Sorry gaurav, the message is unrelated to this.